# Transform between datetime formats

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am facing a problem in which I need to transform dates in a given input format into a target one. Is there any standard way to do this in C#?

As an example say we have `yyyy.MM.dd` as the source format and the target format is `MM/dd/yyy` (current culture).

The problem arises since I am using a parsing strategy that gives priority to the current culture and then if it fails it tries to parse from a list of known formats. Now say we have two equivalent dates one in the source culture above (`2015.12.9`) and the other in the current culture (`9/12/2015`). Then if we attempt to parse this two dates the month will be 12 for the first case and in the second will be 9, so we have an inconsistency (they were supposed to mean be the same exact date).

I believe that if existing it should be something as

```
DateTime.Convert(2015.12.9, 'yyyy/MM/dd', CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Thank you all for your ideas and suggestions, however the interpretation most of you gave to my question was not quite right. What most of you have answered is a direct parse in the given format and then a conversion to the CurrentCulture.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2015.12.9", "yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

This will still return 12 as month, although it is in the CurrentCulture format. My question thus was, is there any standard way to transform the date in `yyyy.MM.d` to the format  `MM/dd/yyy` so that the month is now in the correct place and `THEN` parsed it in the target culture. Such function is likely to be unexisting.

Comment: Or, [Datetime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes format information (example on linked page).

Comment: What will you do if the current culture is `yyyy-mm-dd` and the incoming date is `09/12/2015`? You can't know whether the incoming date is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Exactly. I gave up on this. It was a requirement from my supervisor, but I just convinced him that it is simply impossible, the only way we have to overcome this issue is detecting the format that holds for a given datetime in the data and then restarting the parsing forcing its use until a format is found that parses all data correctly.

Comment: You should be more specific in your first sentence as "in any format" is a very generic problem and as Matthew Watson pointed out you run into logical inconsistancies here like dd/mm and mm/dd so its pretty much impossible, your second sentence indicates you have a single input format as shown. Can you narrow the problem down to a specific format of inputs?

Comment: @JPK, does my edit clarify this?

Comment: @user3853059 +1 for effort and interest in your work! You turned a "bad" question into a better one and yes it does your question is now very answerable and in general shows you want one specific input format translated into another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2015.12.9", "yyyy.MM.d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or eventualy [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're not confident with input string.

Comment: You can check all available format here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I try to explain little bit deep if you let me..

> I am facing a problem in which I need to transform dates in any format
>   to a target one.

There no such a thing as *dates in any format*. A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just has date and time values. Looks like you have a `string` which formatted as date and you want to convert another `string` with *different* format.

> Is there any standard way to do this in C#?

Yes. You can parse your `string` with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) first with specific format to `DateTime` and then generate it's `string` representation with a different format.

> As an example say we have yyyy.MM.dd as the source format and the
>   target format is MM/dd/yyy (current culture).

I didn't understand what is the meaning of *current culture* in this sentences and I assume you want `yyyy` not `yyy`, but you can generate it as I described above like;

```
string source = "2015.12.9";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yyyy.MM.d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string target = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 12/09/201
```

> The problem arises since I am using a parsing strategy that gives
>   priority to the current culture and then if it fails it tries to parse
>   from a list of known formats.

Since you didn't show *any* parsing strategy and there is no `DateTime.Convert` method in .NET Framework, I couldn't any comment.

> Now say we have two equivalent dates one in the source culture above
>   (2015.12.9) and the other in the current culture (9/12/2015). Then if
>   we attempt to parse this two dates the month will be 12 and in the
>   second will be 9, so we have an inconsistency.

Again.. You *don't* have `DateTime`'s. You *have* `string`s. And those formatted strings can't belong on *any* culture. Sure all cultures *might* parse or generate different string representations with the same format format a format does not *belong* any culture.

I assume you have 2 different string which different formatted and you wanna parse the input no matter which one it comes. In such a case, you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes string array for all possible formats as a parameter. Then generate it's string representation with `MM/dd/yyy` format and a culture that has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) like `InvariantCulture`.

```
string s = "2015.12.9"; // or 9/12/2015
string[] formats = { "yyyy.MM.d", "d/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not explicit enough, the dates are strings, but they could be in any format, that is not known apriori; it is detected on current's culture parsing failure. This is, I do a DateTime.TryParse(s, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out datetimevalue) and then if this fails I do DateTime.TryParseExact(str, dateFmts, culture,  out datetimevalue)

Comment: @user3853059 I'm sorry but you can **not** parse every possible formatted string with a single method. You _have to_ know which format string you have so it can be parses successfully. If you get this as an input from somewhere, maybe would be better to use some validation in UI side. Other than that, not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple and Best way to do it is Using .ToString() Method
See this code:

```
DateTime x =DateTime.Now;
```

To Convert This Just Write like This:

```
x.ToString("yyyyMMdd")//20151210
x.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd)//2015/12/10
x.ToString("yyyy/MMM/dd)//2015/DEC/10  //Careful About M type should be capital for month .
```

Hope helpful